# Use regex pattern to replace numbers followed by a substring or numbers followed by a space and then substring

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regexp-replace

For a column in a pandas dataframe, I want to remove any number either immediately followed by "gb" or "mb" or with a space in-between, in it's entirety. I.e. remove strings such as "500 gb" and "500mb".

```
    Column_To_Fix
0   coolblue 100gb
1   connector 500 mb for thing
2   5gb for user
3   load 800 mb
4   1000 add-on
5   20 gb
```

The function below only works for row 0 and row 2, not sure how to add in the space requirement for the pattern:

```
pat = '(^|\s)\d+(gb|mb)($|\s)'
df['Column_To_Fix'].str.lower().replace(pat, ' ', regex=True)
```

Desired Output:

```
    Column_To_Fix
0   coolblue
1   connector for thing
2   for user
3   load
4   1000 add-on
5
```

Comment: Are the numbers `'0'` through `'5'` in the first column part of the text? If not I suggest you remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
pat = '\d+ *(gb|mb)'

df['Column_To_Fix'].str.lower().str.replace(pat, ' ')

Out[462]:
0               coolblue
1    connector   for thing
2                 for user
3                   load
4              1000 add-on
5
Name: Column_To_Fix, dtype: object
```

If you prefer `series.replace`

```
df['Column_To_Fix'].str.lower().replace(pat, ' ', regex=True)
```

Comment: You're preferring to use ' *' over '\s*'. Was just wondering if they both can behave differently in any situation. And a small suggestion..using `'(^|\s)\d+\s*(gb|mb)'` this might avoid the extra space coming in `connector   for thing`

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed the text was (no line numbers):

```
coolblue 100gb
connector 500 mb for thing
5gb for user
load 800 mb
1000 add-on
20 gb
```

and that the desired result (which maintains proper alignment and spacing) was:

```
coolblue
connector for thing
for user
load
1000 add-on
```

with an empty string on the last line. That can be achieved by replacing matches of the following regular expression with empty strings (using `re.sub`).

```
r'(?:^\d+ ?[gm]b | \d+ ?[gm]b(?= |$))'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yiOpvv/1/)